# Equivalence between Maxwell's equations and vector Helmholtz equations

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, vector-fields, calculus

When are equivalent the Maxwell's harmonic equations:
$$
\nabla\times\left(\nabla\times\mathbf{E}\right)=\mu\epsilon\omega^2\mathbf{E}
$$
and the vector Helmholtz equations:
$$
\nabla^2\mathbf{E}=\mu\epsilon\omega^2\mathbf{E}
$$
and when aren't they?

I understand that $\nabla\times\left(\nabla\times\mathbf{u}\right)=\nabla\left(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u}\right)-\nabla^2\mathbf{u}$ for any $\mathbf{u}$ smooth enough, and I know that $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u}$ can be zero by Gauss's law or by taking the divergence of the first equation. So... are they only equivalent when there is no free charge density?

Comment: They are also equivalent when the free charge density is constant (its gradient is zero), but yes, you answered your own question.

Comment: my question was more in the way of "are they only equivalent in that case? (constant free charge density)"

Comment: The answer is still yes. $\nabla(\nabla\cdot E)$ vanishes if and only if the free charge density is constant.